# KeyboardInterrupt: python

Tags: python, compiler-errors, keyboardinterrupt

i have an issue here and i don't know where is the error every thing is right!
the question want me to find the the path and the cost using Uniform cost search algorithm
first I get an error that says NULL, then I get Not itterable type
I fixed them then I get this and I have to submit it in towmowro please help

```
#Write your code here for Question 03
from queue import PriorityQueue
g = dict()
x = input("Enter the number of vertices: ")
i=0
while i< int(x):
    z=input('Enter the number of edges of vertex {}: '.format(i))
    j=0
    t=[]
    while j< int(z):
        a, b= input('Enter the edge {} as vertex and cost seprated by space: '.format(j+1)).split()
        t.append([int(a),int(b)])
        j+=1
    g[i] = t
    i+=1
print()
print('The graph: ')
print(g)
def pathCost(path):
    total=0
    for(node , cost) in path:
        total+=cost
    return total , path[-1][0]

def ucs(g , start , goal):
    visited = []
    pqueue = PriorityQueue([[(start ,0)]])
    while pqueue:
        path=pqueue.get()
        node=path[-1][0]
        if node in visited:
            continue
        visited.append(node)
        if node == goal:
            print("found the goal node")
            return path
        else:  
            adjNodes = g.get(node, [])
            for (node2 , cost) in adjNodes:
                newPath = path.copy()
                newPath.append(node2, cost)
                pqueue.append(newPath)

start = input("Enter the intial vertex: ")
goal = input("Enter the goal vertex: ")
sol = ucs(g , start, goal)
print("The path found by the Uniform cost search is:")
print("The path is: ", sol)
print("The path cost is: ", pathCost(sol))
```

Comment: Please say what inputs you are using then maybe I can help debug it for you

Comment: Enter the number of vertices: 5
Enter the number of edges of vertex 0: 2
Enter the edge 1 as vertex and cost seprated by space: 1 5
Enter the edge 2 as vertex and cost seprated by space: 2 4
Enter the number of edges of vertex 1: 2
Enter the edge 1 as vertex and cost seprated by space: 2 2
Enter the edge 2 as vertex and cost seprated by space: 3 3
Enter the number of edges of vertex 2: 1
Enter the edge 1 as vertex and cost seprated by space: 3 7
Enter the number of edges of vertex 3: 1

Comment: Enter the edge 1 as vertex and cost seprated by space: 4 8
Enter the number of edges of vertex 4: 1
Enter the edge 1 as vertex and cost seprated by space: 3 7

Enter the intial vertex: 0
Enter the goal vertex: 4

Comment: @TomMcLean  this is the input